# Cannot move file: "file cannot be found" (Windows XP)

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, file-transfer

I have some CR2 files in a subfolder of `My Documents` called `My Photos` on a Windows XP PC.

I want to move them across a WIFI network to an external HDD attached to a Windows 7 PC.

I have `read/write` permissions on the external HDD, as I mapped to this HDD using the Windows 7 user account.

When I try to move a single CR2 file, I receive "`Cannot copy IMG_3317: Cannot find the specified file.  Make sure you specify the correct path and file name.`"

If I refresh the source folder, the file is still there.  It is not read only, and I have read/write access to the source file.  I can view its properties.

Why can't I move this file?

I have been able to move similar files in the past.

Comment: Can you copy it to another folder on the same computer? If so, try transferring it from this different location to the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by excessive path lengths. At least that error message would be the same if your folder names plus filename length exceeds Windows limit. 
Check out this question/answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by filesystem errors. Check your disk - open `cmd` as administrator and run command `chkdsk d: /f`

Answer (score 0):

Solved:  Just delete the recycled folder on the affected drive if it only occurs on one drive such as E:\ I tried this and it cured the problem of not being able to delete a file or folder on the drive without using shift+delete.  As soon as I deleted a file after fixing the recycled folder was recreated.  E:\ is boot drive for me the one I have XP files on BTW.